# Error 414: how do I handle large amounts of data returned by GET?

Tags: php, ajax, get

So, I need to be able to return large amounts of data from a database for graphing purposes. Currently, I'm using GET via ajax and simply generating the necessary html via php. This works fine for small amounts of data, but whenever I request more than about a year's worth, I get error 414. Does anyone have suggestions of better ways to do this, or know how to change the limit? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: urls are length-limited. passing more than (at most) 512 chars in a url is just asking for trouble. Use POST instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting a 414 error with the size of  the *return* data from the server, there is no hard limit on the size of an http response.

You ***WILL*** get an error with the size of the URL you are using to ***SEND*** the ajax request, since there are hard limits.

By all means switch to using POST in your ajax calls, ensure that you are sending the data via key/value pairs (not stitched onto the URL itself), and you shouldn't see the error any longer.

**See here for info on URL limits in different browsers (tl;dr stay under 2000):**

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)